# SSL_accept() fails with "SSL routines:SSL_GET_NEW_SESSION:ssl session id callback failed'

Tags: ssl, openssl, hp-ux

I am receiving the following error while trying to accept SSL connection from a client application. I am using openssl version 0.9.8 on HP-UX IA.

> SSL_accept(40107e50) -1 err: 336285997 'error:140B512D:SSL routines:SSL_GET_NEW_SESSION:ssl session id callback failed'

I have checked for /dev/random and /dev/urandom. It exists and functioning properly.

```
 ls -l /dev/random
cr--r--r-- 1 root sys 144 0x000000 Mar 10 2010 /dev/random

cr--r--r-- 1 root sys 144 0x000001 Mar 10 2010 /dev/urandom
```

Please help me in identifying the root cause of the problem.

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur when OpenSSL's PRNG is not sufficiently seeded.  Check on it with RAND_status(), and seed as necessary with RAND_add() or RAND_seed().  http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RAND_add.html